# Android: GCM Push Notification sent successfully from server side but not getting it on client side

Tags: android, android-activity, google-cloud-messaging

I am sending GCM push notification from my server side app and it is showing success but I am not getting those messages on my device. My Google api key and Reg id is also correct here I am posting my android code. Please check and tell what wrong I am doing in this code.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.gcm.cuser.gcmnotification" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".HomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_home" >
        </activity>
        <receiver
            android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <!-- <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" /> -->
                <category android:name="@string/app_name" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.gcm.cuser.gcmnotification;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging;
import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient;
import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler;
import com.loopj.android.http.RequestParams;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ProgressDialog prgDialog;
    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcmObj;
    Context applicationContext;
    String regId = "";

    private final static int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;

    AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> createRegIdTask;

    public static final String REG_ID = "regId";
    public static final String EMAIL_ID = "eMailId";
    EditText emailET;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        applicationContext = getApplicationContext();
        emailET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);

        prgDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        // Set Progress Dialog Text
        prgDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        // Set Cancelable as False
        prgDialog.setCancelable(false);

        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("UserDetails",
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String registrationId = prefs.getString(REG_ID, "");

        //When Email ID is set in Sharedpref, User will be taken to HomeActivity
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(registrationId)) {
            Intent i = new Intent(applicationContext, HomeActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("regId", registrationId);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    }

    // When Register Me button is clicked
    public void RegisterUser(View view) {
        String emailID = emailET.getText().toString();

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(emailID) && Utility.validate(emailID)) {

            // Check if Google Play Service is installed in Device
            // Play services is needed to handle GCM stuffs
            if (checkPlayServices()) {

                // Register Device in GCM Server
                registerInBackground(emailID);
            }
        }
        // When Email is invalid
        else {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Please enter valid email",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

    // AsyncTask to register Device in GCM Server
    private void registerInBackground(final String emailID) {
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                String msg = "";
                try {
                    if (gcmObj == null) {
                        gcmObj = GoogleCloudMessaging
                                .getInstance(applicationContext);
                    }
                    regId = gcmObj
                            .register(ApplicationConstants.GOOGLE_PROJ_ID);
                    msg = "Registration ID :" + regId;
                    Log.d("msg1", msg);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();
                }
                return msg;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(regId)) {
                    // Store RegId created by GCM Server in SharedPref
                    storeRegIdinSharedPref(applicationContext, regId, emailID);
                    Toast.makeText(
                            applicationContext,
                            "Registered with GCM Server successfully.\n\n"
                                    + msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(
                            applicationContext,
                            "Reg ID Creation Failed.\n\nEither you haven't enabled Internet or GCM server is busy right now. Make sure you enabled Internet and try registering again after some time."
                                    + msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }.execute(null, null, null);
    }

    // Store  RegId and Email entered by User in SharedPref
    private void storeRegIdinSharedPref(Context context, String regId,
                                        String emailID) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("UserDetails",
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString(REG_ID, regId);
        editor.putString(EMAIL_ID, emailID);
        editor.commit();
        storeRegIdinServer();

    }

    // Share RegID with GCM Server Application (Php)
    private void storeRegIdinServer() {
        prgDialog.show();
        params.put("regId", regId);
        // Make RESTful webservice call using AsyncHttpClient object
        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        client.post(ApplicationConstants.APP_SERVER_URL, params,
                new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
                    // When the response returned by REST has Http
                    // response code '200'

                    public void onSuccess(String response) {
                        // Hide Progress Dialog
                        prgDialog.hide();
                        if (prgDialog != null) {
                            prgDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                        Toast.makeText(applicationContext,
                                "Reg Id shared successfully with Web App ",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Intent i = new Intent(applicationContext,
                                HomeActivity.class);
                        i.putExtra("regId", regId);
                        startActivity(i);
                        finish();
                    }

                    // When the response returned by REST has Http
                    // response code other than '200' such as '404',
                    // '500' or '403' etc

                    public void onFailure(int statusCode, Throwable error,
                                          String content) {
                        // Hide Progress Dialog
                        prgDialog.hide();
                        if (prgDialog != null) {
                            prgDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                        // When Http response code is '404'
                        if (statusCode == 404) {
                            Toast.makeText(applicationContext,
                                    "Requested resource not found",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        // When Http response code is '500'
                        else if (statusCode == 500) {
                            Toast.makeText(applicationContext,
                                    "Something went wrong at server end",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        // When Http response code other than 404, 500
                        else {
                            Toast.makeText(
                                    applicationContext,
                                    "Unexpected Error occcured! [Most common Error: Device might "
                                            + "not be connected to Internet or remote server is not up and running], check for other errors as well",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    // Check if Google Playservices is installed in Device or not
    private boolean checkPlayServices() {
        int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil
                .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        // When Play services not found in device
        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
                // Show Error dialog to install Play services
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,
                        PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(
                        applicationContext,
                        "This device doesn't support Play services, App will not work normally",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            }
            return false;
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(
                    applicationContext,
                    "This device supports Play services, App will work normally",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return true;
    }

    // When Application is resumed, check for Play services support to make sure app will be running normally
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        checkPlayServices();
    }
}
```

HomeActivity.java

```
package com.gcm.cuser.gcmnotification;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class HomeActivity extends Activity {
    TextView msgET, usertitleET;

    private final static int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        // Intent Message sent from Broadcast Receiver
        String str = getIntent().getStringExtra("msg");

        // Get Email ID from Shared preferences
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("UserDetails",
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String eMailId = prefs.getString("eMailId", "");
        // Set Title
        usertitleET = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.usertitle);

        // Check if Google Play Service is installed in Device
        // Play services is needed to handle GCM stuffs
        if (!checkPlayServices()) {
            Toast.makeText(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    "This device doesn't support Play services, App will not work normally",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        usertitleET.setText("Hello " + eMailId + " !");
        // When Message sent from Broadcase Receiver is not empty
        if (str != null) {
            // Set the message
            msgET = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message);
            msgET.setText(str);
        }
    }

    // Check if Google Playservices is installed in Device or not
    private boolean checkPlayServices() {
        int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil
                .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        // When Play services not found in device
        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
                // Show Error dialog to install Play services
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,
                        PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        "This device doesn't support Play services, App will not work normally",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            }
            return false;
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    "This device supports Play services, App will work normally",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return true;
    }

    // When Application is resumed, check for Play services support to make sure
    // app will be running normally
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        checkPlayServices();
    }
}
```

GcmBroadcastReciever.java

```
package com.gcm.cuser.gcmnotification;

/**
 * Created by cuser on 28/9/15.
 */
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.content.WakefulBroadcastReceiver;

public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                GCMNotificationIntentService.class.getName());
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }
}
```

GcmNotificationIntentService.java

```
package com.gcm.cuser.gcmnotification;

/**
 * Created by cuser on 28/9/15.
 */
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;

import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging;

public class GCMNotificationIntentService extends IntentService {
    // Sets an ID for the notification, so it can be updated
    public static final int notifyID = 9001;
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

    public GCMNotificationIntentService() {
        super("GcmIntentService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);

        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

        if (!extras.isEmpty()) {
            if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR
                    .equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED
                    .equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: "
                        + extras.toString());
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE
                    .equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("Message Received from Google GCM Server:\n\n"
                        + extras.get(ApplicationConstants.MSG_KEY));
            }
        }
        GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }

    private void sendNotification(String msg) {
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
        resultIntent.putExtra("msg", msg);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mNotifyBuilder;
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager;

        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("Alert")
                .setContentText("You've received new message.")
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        // Set pending intent
        mNotifyBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

        // Set Vibrate, Sound and Light
        int defaults = 0;
        defaults = defaults | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
        defaults = defaults | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        defaults = defaults | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

        mNotifyBuilder.setDefaults(defaults);
        // Set the content for Notification
        mNotifyBuilder.setContentText("New message from Server");
        // Set autocancel
        mNotifyBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        // Post a notification
        mNotificationManager.notify(notifyID, mNotifyBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Utility.java

```
package com.gcm.cuser.gcmnotification;

/**
 * Created by cuser on 28/9/15.
 */
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
/**
 * Class which has Utility methods
 *
 */
public class Utility {
    private static Pattern pattern;
    private static Matcher matcher;
    //Email Pattern
    private static final String EMAIL_PATTERN =
            "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"
                    + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";

    /**
     * Validate Email with regular expression
     *
     * @param email
     * @return true for Valid Email and false for Invalid Email
     */
    public static boolean validate(String email) {
        pattern = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN);
        matcher = pattern.matcher(email);
        return matcher.matches();
    }
}
```

ApplicationConstants.java

```
package com.gcm.cuser.gcmnotification;

/**
 * Created by cuser on 28/9/15.
 */
public interface ApplicationConstants {

    // Php Application URL to store Reg ID created
    static final String APP_SERVER_URL = "http://assign.afterklass.in/gcm/gcm.php?shareRegId=true";

    // Google Project Number
    static final String GOOGLE_PROJ_ID = "847402657944";
    // Message Key
    static final String MSG_KEY = "m";

}
```

Comment: change your <category name with your package name may work

Comment: i am telling about this <category android:name="@string/app_name"

Answer (score 1):

You doesn't added service in your mainfest. Just add this in manifest

```
<!-- services -->
        <service android:name=".GCMNotificationIntentService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

I think it works.

Answer (score 0):

The intent filter category should be your package name not you application name.

```
<receiver android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <!-- <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" /> --> 
        <category android:name="com.gcm.cuser.gcmnotification" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```